# how to remain position alltought rectangle was hidden in rdlc Report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I insert a rectangle on the top of a report and set Visible = Hide 
under the rectangle has a textbox.
But when report was loaded. A textbox will move up replace rectangle was hidden.

How to remain a position of the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Move your `Hide` action to the items within the rectangle, but leave the rectangle itself visible.